# Pasting from clipboard in vim

Tags: vim, ubuntu-14.04, paste

I am trying to paste a string I copied from a webpage in vim. I know that the string is copied in the system clipboard. My vim returns 1 when I run the `:echo has('clipboard')` command, so I typed `:set paste`, then positioned the cursor to the desired spot and hit `"*p`, but this doesn't seem to paste my whole selection. I copied to the clipboard `Vader(father figure)` but it only pastes `Vader`. Or is it pasting this because the word behind the cursor is `Vader`? And finally, what is the easiest way to paste something in vim from the system's clipboard?

I mention that I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (if this has any relevance).

Comment: I always install `gvim` for example with the package `vim-gtk`, afterwards vim's + register will be synced with the clipboard. Even for the normal vim which runs in the terminal.

Comment: I already have installed the vim-gtk package (`sudo apt-get install vim-gtk`). I was wondering how to actually paste my selection to the document. Is either `"*p` or `"+p` correct?

Comment: The latter should be correct.

Comment: I got this info from the Vim wiki, and it helped, but now the information may be stale.   When you evaluate :set clipboard, the default is autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux With Vim, you can prepend (don't append, as exclude needs to be last, (which may be stale info)) with `set clipboard^=unnamed` (X11 clibboard) or `set clipboard^=unnamedplus` GNOME System clipboard.  Current help says unnamed is the `*` register and unnamedplus is `+` (and mentions nothing about GNOME versus X11). At the time, using ^= and not += fixed clipboard access on Fedora with XFCE 4.10

Comment: @Polb if the provided solution works as expected please accept it or explain why it's not working for you. I'll try to adjust it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I always use `Ctrl+Shift+v` in Insert mode, when pasting from system clipboard after doing  `set paste`. Never had any problems doing so.

Otherwise you can use the vim-unimpaired plugin by tim pope and use the `yo` key mapping set by the plugin to paste. Using `yo` automatically sets the paste option and after you paste and leave Insert mode, it automatically toggles the set paste option.

Answer (score 0):

Have this line in your .vimrc

```
set pastetoggle=<F2>
```

So whenever you press F2 in insert mode you can paste normally with no problems.
For more information refer [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_auto-indenting_for_code_paste).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to `set paste` if you intend to paste while in insert mode using the middle mouse button or any shortcut your terminal provides.

Now, it is possible that the register you're looking for is quote+. To confirm that just run `:registers` in order to view the contents of all registers.

I would also advise you to read the following help section `:help x11-selection`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using the system clipboard in vim as default register in combination with a clipboard manager like [Diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon) or Klipper (for KDE).

Add this to your vim configuration `~/.vimrc`

```
" Use the system clipboard for yank / delete / paste operations 
if has('unnamedplus')
   set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
endif
```

With this configuration vim copy/paste operations (in both directions) behave just like in any other graphical editor (the `if has ('unnamedplus')` assure that this behaviour is enabled only if vim is compiled with the *+clipboard* option otherwise behaves as default).

**Note**: on Windows and MacOS using *unnamed* or *unnamedplus* is equivalent.

On Linux are two different entities:

- **unnamed** register is the *selection* buffer (try to select something with the mouse and then center click or click both sx and dx mouse buttons in another place).
- **unnamedplus** register is actually the system clipboard